# Failed to render template <Template memory:7f8cb04ad190> using values ... - ODOO 10.0 Community

Tags: python, templates, odoo-10

I am using ODOO 10.0 Community. I did some changes in "Sales Order - Send by Email" email template (Settings -> Emails -> Templates) and I did translation of this template for es_DO.

After that, when I try send a quotation by email, I get this error:

```
Odoo Warning

Failed to render template <Template memory:7f8c9c7b5110> using values {'format_amount': <function <lambda> at 0x7f8c9c551c80>, 'object': mail.message(257,), 'ctx': {u'uid': 1, 'button_access': {'url': '/mail/view?message_id=257', 'title': u'View Sales Order'}, 'mail_notify_user_signature': False, 'has_button_unfollow': False, u'default_use_template': True, u'search_disable_custom_filters': True, u'default_model': u'sale.order', u'default_res_id': 4, u'tz': u'America/Santo_Domingo', u'mark_so_as_sent': True, 'mail_post_autofollow': True, 'followers': res.partner(156,), 'has_button_access': True, 'subtype': mail.message.subtype(1,), 'button_follow': {'url': '/mail/follow?model=sale.order&res_id=4&token=0c1274d07d0d176e511da3b08529c6951df5347f', 'title': u'Follow'}, u'custom_layout': u'sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order', 'signature': False, 'website_url': u'http://www.company.com.do', 'company_name': u'COMPANY NAME', u'default_template_id': 15, 'record_name': u'SO004', u'hide_sale': True, u'default_composition_mode': u'comment', 'actions': [], u'active_id': 4, u'lang': u'en_US', 'tracking': [], 'is_discussion': True, u'active_model': u'sale.order', 'not_followers': res.partner(), 'record': sale.order(4,), u'params': {u'action': 362}, 'mail_auto_delete': True, u'active_ids': [4], 'has_button_follow': False, 'model_name': u'Sales Order', 'button_unfollow': {'url': '/mail/unfollow?model=sale.order&res_id=4&token=44620a2a177721c9c1dddc41c3d6fbd08f90d5957de', 'title': u'Unfollow'}}, 'format_tz': <function <lambda> at 0x7f8c9c551848>, 'user': res.users(1,), 'format_date': <function <lambda> at 0x7f8c9c551aa0>}
```

Looking into the logs, I found this:

> UndefinedError: 'odoo.api.mail.message object' has no attribute 'partner_id'

Full log about this issue:

```
2017-08-14 03:08:55,658 19561 INFO odoo_beta odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_template: Failed to render template using values     {'format_amount': <function at 0x7fa6d43eeb90>, 'object': mail.message(234,), 'ctx': {u'uid': 3, 'button_access': {'url': '/mail/view?message_id=234', 'title': u'
View Sales Order'}, 'mail_notify_user_signature': False, 'has_button_unfollow': False, u'default_use_template':
True, u'search_disable_custom_filters': True, u'default_model': u'sale.order', u'default_res_id': 2, u'tz': u'
America/Santo_Domingo', u'mark_so_as_sent': True, 'mail_post_autofollow': True, 'followers': res.partner(11, 1)
'has_button_access': True, 'subtype': mail.message.subtype(1,), 'button_follow': {'url': '/mail/follow?model=
sale.order&res_id=2&token=edee5095495480e0a46e7019aa0b46992ase2', 'title': u'Follow'}, u'custom_layout': u's
ale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order', 'signature': False, 'website_url': u'https://www.beta odoo.
com.do', 'company_name': u'beta odoo TEAM SRL', u'default_template_id': 15, 'record_name': u'SO002', u'hide_sale'
: True, u'default_composition_mode': u'comment', 'actions': [], u'active_id': 2, u'lang': u'en_US', 'tracking':
[], 'is_discussion': True, u'active_model': u'sale.order', 'not_followers': res.partner(), 'record': sale.orde
r(2,), u'params': {u'action': 362, u'model': u'sale.order', u'_push_me': False, u'id': 2, u'view_type': u'form'},'mail_auto_delete': True, u'active_ids': [2], 'has_button_follow': False, 'model_name': u'Sales Order', 'button_unfollow': {'url': '/mail/unfollow?model=sale.order&res_id=2&token=79f5c1284c94f653aea7210abc5cfa204d58a0cc', 'title': u'Unfollow'}}, 'format_tz': <function at 0x7fa6d43eeb18>, 'user': res.users(1,), 'format_date': <function at 0x7fa6d43ee848>}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/beta odoo/www/odoo_beta odoo/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py", line 394, in render_template
render_result = template.render(variables)

File "/home/beta odoo/www/odoo_beta odoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/home/beta odoo/www/odoo_beta odoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "", line 1, in top-level template code
File "/home/beta odoo/www/odoo_beta odoo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 329, in getattr
value = getattr(obj, attribute)
UndefinedError: 'odoo.api.mail.message object' has no attribute 'partner_id'
```

I try removed my translation, left empty the template and nothing seems work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: search for the position where you used `partner_id`. The error must be somewhere there.

Comment: Would you share your python code, template file and view file. I have idea to solve this

Answer (score 1):

After of hours and hours debugging, I found the error for my issue.

In Settings => Email -> Templales => Sale Order Notification Email.   Then in tab "Advanced Settings"   I set the value for language field:  ${object.partner_id.lang},  that in order to get this template multi-language, just as the help tooltip for this field said, but this throw the error.

Tooltip Screenshot:  https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=AvphfTf2THpwh5E&cid=1B8E966532F20D97&id=1B8E966532F20D97%21277&parId=1B8E966532F20D97%21105&o=OneUp

I didn't realize what that was the problem because I did a lot of changes before I detect the problem.

I hope my experience helps others and if this is an error in ODOO (at least in the tooltip), can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the user couldn't access to one of my custom model, so all i did is give read acces to it

**always read the log**